# How can we clone groups like clone field in system.xml in Mageno 2?

Tags: magento2, system.xml, system-configuration

In system.xml file, for cloning the fields we use **clone_fields** and **clone_model**. Here is the example:

```
<group id="placeholder" translate="label" sortOrder="300" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Product Image Placeholders</label>
    <clone_fields>1</clone_fields>
    <clone_model>Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\CatalogClone\Media\Image</clone_model>
    <field id="placeholder" type="image" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
        <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">catalog/product/placeholder</upload_dir>
        <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">catalog/product/placeholder</base_url>
    </field>
</group>
```

Above code gives output like this
[image]

What I want is to copy fields with group like

> ```
> Prefix1_Group
>     -> prifix1_image (field)
> Prefix2_Group
>     -> prifix2_image (field)
> Prefix3_Group
>     -> prifix3_image (field)
> ```

I have set of fields which are repeating in different group with group_name prefix.
Please let me know if there is any other way to do this.
Thank you.